# setOnItemClickListener for activity extending ListActivity without adapter

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I want to implement a setOnItemClickListener for the below mentioned listview.
The code works fine for me in displaying items of string-array to listview but I want to perform some action when the user clicks and on longclick.

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity{

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    String[] plainStrings = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.myarray);
    Spanned[] htmlStrings = new Spanned[plainStrings.length];
    for(int i = 0 ; i < plainStrings.length; i++) {
        htmlStrings[i] = Html.fromHtml(plainStrings[i]);
    }
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this,R.layout.items, htmlStrings));
 }
```

main_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:isScrollContainer="true"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay">

 <ListView
   android:id="@android:id/list"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:clickable="true"
   android:dividerHeight="3dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

items.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/text1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: Using directly setOnItemClickListener and setOnItemLongClickListener

Comment: @SpiderMan .yes I want to know if its possible..I want the position of item clicked in listview so that I can provide options like copy and share for instance..

Answer (score 0):

`ListActivity` has its own protected method [onListItemClick](https://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html#onListItemClick(android.widget.ListView,%20android.view.View,%20int,%20long)), you can override it to get the *row click*'s event

Answer (score 0):

Normal click:

```
      listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
        //Do whatever you want                 

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
```

Long click:

```
 listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                final int arg2, long arg3) {
//Do whatever you want
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Long Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        });
    }
```

Comment: I want the position of item clicked in listview so that I can provide options like copy and share for instance but as the id of listview is "android:id".. it doesn't return the position

Comment: `int position` parameter in method gives the position of item.